# DepthFirstTraversal Graph recursion testing

Tags: java, recursion

So I have written a solution that(hopefully) works, however I don't know exactly how to test if it is working properly. In the recursion method sor.edges() simply iterates through the adjacent edges. If any other methods need clarification just let me know. Thanks.

```
public static List<String> depthFirstSearch(Graph graph, String startName, String goalName)
{
Vertex source = new Vertex(startName);
    Vertex dest = new Vertex(goalName);
    ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(!(graph.getVertices().containsKey(startName) || graph.getVertices().containsKey(goalName)))
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

    if(startName.equals(goalName))
    {
        returnList.add(startName);
        return returnList;
    }

    return DFS(source, dest);
}

private static List<String> DFS(Vertex sor, Vertex des)
{
    ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(!sor.getName().equals(des.getName()))
    sor.setVisited(true);
    Iterator<Edge> iterator = sor.edges();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Vertex nextVertex = iterator.next().getOtherVertex();
        if(!nextVertex.getVisited())
        {
            nextVertex.setCameFrom(sor);
            returnList.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) sor.getCameFrom());
            return DFS(nextVertex, des);
        }

    }
    return returnList;


}
```

Comment: On a complete side note to your question, you probably want to throw an IllegalArguementException vs an UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Their really isn't an (easy) automated way to test this. My suggestion would be to throw in some simple graphs and hand test that the outputs are as expected. The other option is two test. The first is a connected graph because there will exist a path from start to finish, you just want to confirm that this does generate a path. The second would be a disjoint graph where first and last are not connected, here their will be a failure or something analogous.